# Dokku postgres service name and database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dokku

When I created my Ruby on Rails application, I used the Unix “dot” convention to refer to the current directory. My current directory's name was `fireworks_app`, so my application was given the name of `fireworks_app`.

The `database.yml` file was created accordingly, so that for each environment the corresponding database was named with the formula `fireworks_app_environment`.

I would like to install Dokku in my VPS.
I wonder what alternatives do I have to naming my Dokku application `fireworks_app`, and the Dokku postgres service respecting what is reported in `database.yml` (`fireworks_app_production`).

This would imply that I create my Dokku application and  my postgres service as follows:

```
$ dokku apps:create fireworks_app
$ dokku postgres:create fireworks_app_production
$ dokku postgres:link fireworks_app_production fireworks_app
```

This looks to me a bit awkward: there is no need to specify *production* for my VPS, for instance. 
Instead, I would prefer to name my application `fireworks` and all my services `fireworks`. Thus I would use instead the following more compact commands and names:

```
$ dokku apps:create fireworks
$ dokku postgres:create fireworks
$ dokku postgres:link fireworks fireworks
```

Is it possible in this regard to edit `database.yml` and change `fireworks_app_production` into a more compact `fireworks`? What changes can I (and am I expected to) do to avoid appending `_app` and `_app_production` to my Dokku application and service names?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to worry about the database.yml file, you can do this if you want without problems

```
$ dokku apps:create fireworks
$ dokku postgres:create fireworks
$ dokku postgres:link fireworks fireworks
```

you can use the name that you want on the app and on postgres. just be sure that you link the ones that you created, no mater the name.